# I am frequently getting error for workbench

Tags: workbench

[image]

The workbench fails when i try to login.As you can see we have  domain name changed  for our org  and URL is quite different.Do you think its because of that?

Please if anybody can point out why that happens will be great

Comment: Are you using your own workbench instance or the one at workbench.developerforce.com?

Answer (score 3):

The [developer force workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) definitely works for organizations that have a custom domain for both sandbox and production. Make sure to choose the correct environment when accessing a sandbox. I would raise a case with salesforce support as this is an internal error on their side.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this happened during the OAuth login flow from Workbench, but this is an internal server error coming back from Salesforce, not Workbench. Notice the URL is for host cs3.salesforce.com. If you're still having this error, the best thing to do is to file a support ticket with Salesforce and provide them the error number so they can look up what happened on the backend.